# selecting option for mat-select dropdown and retrieving selected option using cypress

Tags: angular-material, cypress

I have a mat-select dropdown with more than 20 values. I have to select a value from the available list. The first 5 values are visible when the dropdown is clicked. After that, the values in the dropdown are not visible and unable to click.

```js
cy.get('app-screen').find('#paper-code').click());
cy.contains('mat-option', 'AL019').should('be.visible').click();
```

Since the above code failed, updated the code as below.

```js
cy.contains('mat-option', 'AL019').click();
```

This worked. But, will it get failed anytime later?
Another question, is how to get the selected option for mat-select?

Answer (score 0):

It could fail later but it won't if you set the force option to true and avoid having to wait for an actionable state.

```
cy.contains('mat-option', 'AL019').click({ force:true });
```

Answer (score 0):

If it does fail in the future, you want to know about it because there's a regression in the app.

Don't `{force:true}` unless you really really need to, because it will stop your test catching such regressions.

To test the value is selected may be as simple as

```js
cy.get('app-screen').find('#paper-code').should('contain', 'AL019)
```